# What is the best practice to switch the language of a running java program

Tags: java, properties

How can I switch between languages in a running Java program? How can I change all text / labels in the GUI without much effort.

Answer (score 2):

Study: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/

Making your application support localization is not an effortless procedure. It requires upfront thought and design. But after that you can add languages very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check up on resource bundles and locales.